# Mongodb Atlas Charts - Show grouped count in different columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-charts

I have a collection of "ofertas" in my DB and the data has this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6057a995e5a26c119d254f35"),
    "empresa" : {
        "direccion" : {
            "direccion" : "concepcion arenal",
            "cp" : "36950",
            "provincia" : "pontevedra",
            "poblacion" : "Moaña",
            "pais" : "espana"
        },
        "nombre" : "caru sl"
    },
    "nombre_oferta" : "Offer Name",
    "referencia_interna" : "111222",
    "fecha_publicacion" : ISODate("2021-03-21T23:00:00.000Z"),
    "fecha_caducidad" : ISODate("2021-04-19T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "descripcion" : "Offer description",
    "estado" : "caducada",
    "pagada" : true,
    "userId" : "XXX",
    "candidatos" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-03-21T20:16:21.438Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-04-20T22:08:14.221Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And I have this MongoDB query:

```
[
    { $sortByCount: "$empresa.nombre" },
    {$group: {
         _id: 0,
         empresas_ofertas:{$push: {
             empresa:"$_id",
             ofertas:"$count",
         }},
    }},
    { $unwind: "$empresas_ofertas"}
]
```

That groups the number of "ofertas", like this:

[image: query result]

And I want to show data in MongoDB Atlas Charts as separated columns with the count of "ofertas" for each object of the "empresas_ofertas" array, but the chart just show one column with the total amount of "ofertas":

[image: atlas chart]

I changed the Y axis Aggregate from SUM to COUNT BY VALUE but it groups the data with the items that have the same amount of "ofertas". What I'm trying to do is to show all the objects in the "empresas_ofertas" array with the count of ofertas: first column should be 60 (IXAS Value SL), second columns should be 53 (caru sl)...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you please post your data as snippets. We do recommend not to post img files

Comment: Yes of course, I added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STEP 1 - CREATING A QUERY**

Your query is good. It will return the data that you need to create a requested chart. I tested it, and you will got as a response data in this format:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "empresas_ofertas": {
      "empresa": "caru sl 2",
      "ofertas": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "empresas_ofertas": {
      "empresa": "caru sl 1",
      "ofertas": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gpn9trcgfsK

**STEP 2 - DEFINING AXES**

As it can be seen in your picture, in the left menu list you have the `_id` field and  `empresas_ofertas` object field with nested `empresa` and `ofertas` fields. That is the data structure that is returned from the query.

On the right of that list, there a section where you should define `X Axis` and `Y Axis` from the available data (`_id`, `empresas_ofertas.empresa` and `empresas_ofertas.ofertas`). Note that right now, you didn't specify the `X Axis` at all, as you can see in the image.

All you have to do is to Drag-and-Drop `empresa` nested field to the `X Axis`, and `ofertas` to the `Y Axis`. That will display your requested chart.

Comment: Yes!! That did the trick. Just one point, to show the data as expected I had to put the axis data in the opposite way: empresa in the X Axis, and ofertas in the Y Axis. Thanks for your response!!